# I am struck in a problem and need help in finding monotonicity of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have done few steps while finding the monotonicity of sequence .My work is in attachment.kindly help[image contains the question and the step I applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jv7Q0.jpg)

Comment: I would start by substracting $a_n$ from $a_{n+1}$ (find common denominator) and try to show if it is always positive.

Comment: Please don't use pictures.
Use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Please edit the question to type the problem and the step you applied directly into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two opportunities to know. You can divide $\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}$ if you get something, that less than 1, then the sequence is decreasing ( if greater than 1, then increasing) or you can subract $a_n-a_{n+1}$ if you get something negative, then the sequence is decreasing (if something positiv, then increasing)

Comment: I think you need to switch $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ in your answer for it to be correct.  If you compute $a_{n+1}-a_n$, you get something that is obviously positive, so the sequence monotonically increases.  I think this is the most straightforward approach.